# elasticsearch return hits found in aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to get rows from my database that have a unique 'sku' field.

I have a working query which counts this number correctly, my query:

```
GET _search
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
  "unique_products":{  
    "cardinality":{
      "field":"sku.keyword"
    }  
  }
},
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "(merch1: 'Dog') AND ((store_name: 'walmart')) AND product_gap: 'yes'"
        }
      },
      {
        "range": {
          "capture_date": {
            "format": "date",
            "gte": "2020-05-13",
            "lte": "2020-08-03"
          }
        }
      } 
    ]
  }
}

}
```

Returns this result:

```
{
  "took" : 129,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 514,
    "successful" : 514,
    "skipped" : 98,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 150,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "unique_products" : {
      "value" : 38
    }
  }
}
```

Which correctly reports the number of unique_products as 38.

I am trying to edit this query so that it will actually return all 38 unique products, but am unsure how, I started by trying to return the top hit from the agg result:

```
GET _search
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
  "unique_products":{  
    "cardinality":{
      "field":"sku.keyword"
    }  
  },
  "top_hits": {
    "size": 1,
    "_source": {
      "include": [
        "sku", "source_store"
      ]
    }
  }
},
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "(merch1: 'Dog') AND ((store_name: 'walmart')) AND product_gap: 'yes'"
        }
      },
      {
        "range": {
          "capture_date": {
            "format": "date",
            "gte": "2020-05-13",
            "lte": "2020-08-03"
          }
        }
      } 
    ]
  }
}

}
```

But got an error in my result saying:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Expected [START_OBJECT] under [size], but got a [VALUE_NUMBER] in [top_hits]",
        "line": 10,
        "col": 13
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Expected [START_OBJECT] under [size], but got a [VALUE_NUMBER] in [top_hits]",
    "line": 10,
    "col": 13
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Is a cardinality agg still my best bet for returning all 38 unique products? thanks

Answer (score 0):

While the cardinality aggregation gives the unique count, it cannot accept sub-aggs. In other words `top_hits` cannot be used here directly.

The approach was correct but you may first want to bucketize the `sku`s and then retrieve the underlying docs using `top_hits`:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_products": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "sku.keyword"
      }
    },
    "terms_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "sku.keyword",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_hits_agg": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": {
              "include": [
                "sku",
                "source_store"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "(merch1: 'Dog') AND ((store_name: 'walmart')) AND product_gap: 'yes'"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "capture_date": {
              "format": "date",
              "gte": "2020-05-13",
              "lte": "2020-08-03"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

FYI The reason your query threw an exception is that `top_hits` is an agg **type** and, just like `unique_products`, it was missing its own name.

Comment: thank you, is there some way I can return all values in the 'includes' field? right now it returns the sku and source_store, in my responce 'hits' variable it only appears to have the sku valuein the _source field: ```"hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "chewyfinal-18-07-20201",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "v3uUYXMBqtqyyCl-m9Bh",
                  "_score" : 14.090103,
                  "_source" : {
                    "sku" : "20584263"
                  }
                }
              ]```

Comment: Try `store_name` instead of `source_store` and/or verify that the desired doc does have all the fields you're expecting.

Comment: your right I just had the wrong string, thank you, I have 97 key/value pairs in my original _source object, if I want to return all 97 do I have to put them in indiviually in the includes statement like ```"includes": [
               "upc",
               "sku",
                "store_name_display",
                "otherfield", ..... "field 97"
              ]``` or can i do includes[*] or something to that extent?

Comment: Most certainly. Either `["*"]` or delete the `_source` key :) If my answer helped you, please upvote & accept :)